# Andengine background image performance

Tags: android, andengine

I'm having some trouble using a sprite as background for my scene. I'm setting the background as follows:

```
Sprite bg = new Sprite(SCENE_WIDTH/2 , SCENE_HEIGHT/2, this.mParallaxBackRegion,getVertexBufferObjectManager());
bg.setCullingEnabled(true);
mScene.setBackground(new SpriteBackground(bg));
```

Loading of the texture:

```
this.mParallaxBack = new AssetBitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), this.getAssets(), "gfx/_fixed.png", TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
this.mParallaxBackRegion = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(this.mParallaxBack);
this.mParallaxBack.load();
```

The png I'm loading is a completely black 960x640 image (same as my scene size), for testing purposes. However, setting the background causes my fps to drop from 60 (when not using the background) to 45 on my HTC Desire. I've tried multiple ways of setting the background, but all seem to be causing the same performance hit. Why does this affect the performance so drastically, and is there something I can do about this?

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but you're not initializing the texture during each and every frame, are you?

Comment: Nope, I load it in the onCreateResources function

Answer (score 0):

That is strange that you should get such a big performance hit. But here's one thing to try. Since i seems you likely have other things drawn to the screen besides this background, add the background to the same Texture. OpenGL works faster when there are fewer textures. When openGL has to draw from another texture its switches context *(citation needed) which is a slow operation. So having all your sprites on a single texture makes GL draw calls more efficient. 
This alone is not likely to explain the performance problem.

It could also be your antialiasing setting: TextureOptions.BILINEAR.
Bilinear is the highest quality setting. Try using DEFAULT or NEAREST_PREMULTIPLYALPHA and see if that doesn't help.

Also, set your background to ignore updates.

One last thought: 
The HTC desire is a fairly old phone at this date (released in 2010) the performance will be in part due to it being an old phone with an old version of android. I test on an HTC incredible, about the same vintage, and you have to be very conservative with your image sizes on that device. 
Did you know that you can make your andengine native size 1/2 of the screen size and scale it up using a RatioResolutionPolicy? I used that approach for my first andengine (GLES1) project and had great success on that generation of devices.https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.plonzogame&hl=en